# Should I use honorifics to say (言う 'iu') for subordinate clauses?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, honorifics, word-requests, subordinate-clauses

When I use という *to-iu*, for example:

> これと同{おな}じ「草{くさ}」というものがここに生{は}えますか？
>  *Kore to onaji “kusa” to-iu mono ga kokoni haemasu ka?*
>
> Does something like this so-called “grass” grow around here?

Should I replace いう for “申す *mōsu*” “申し上げる *mōshiageru*” or “おっしゃる *ossharu*” if I use honorifics form?

Are these words interchangeable in all situations?  If not, when do I use each?

-Jerbot

Answer (score 2):

No, because it's not an action that you or the listener does. If anything, the action is done by mankind and you don't need to respect mankind ;) Similarly for e.g. `関西でよく食べられる明石焼をご存知ですか？`. Here, the verb `know` is changed to show respect, but not the verb `eat`.

If the action is performed by a group you need to show respect, that's a different story. E.g.

> 天皇陛下が好んで召し上がった饅頭はどれですか？
>   社長がフロッピーと呼んでおられたのは何ですか？
>   御社でお使いになっているソフトは何ですか？

Another exception is if you are a royalty or something (at least that's how it's depicted in some films etc.)

> サンマと申すものを持って参れ

Here, mankind is below you so you change the verb.